# sub process check output fails in cron job

Tags: python, bash, cron, subprocess

I am running a cronjob which calls a python script which has subprocess checkoutput.

I tried a simple script to debug.

```
import subprocess
import os


command = "/home/sgadamse/history_checker/code/rg \"hello\""
try:
    result = subprocess.check_output(command,shell=True)
    print(result)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e)
```

Output when ran in the shell:
I get the output i needed

```
[~/history_checker/code]$ python a.py                                                                                                                                 

a.py:command = "/home/sgadamse/history_checker/code/rg \"hello\""
```

I created a cron job to run in crontab -e

```
* * * * * python /home/sgadamse/history_checker/code/a.py
```

I get this error when its executed:

```
Command '/home/sgadamse/history_checker/code/rg "hello"' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

/home/sgadamse/history_checker/code/rg is the complete rg binary path that i downloaded and using it.

Do we need to do anything differently for the the cron jobs to execute the subprocess checkoutput?

Thanks.

Edit:
I tried to debug the rg, Its actually running the command but the files its searching is only "stdin" and nothing else
any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Does the script still work in your shell when you run it from your home dir?

Comment: yes it works when i run manually

Comment: From your home dir and not from `~/history_checker/code` right? Is this the standard ripgrep tool or some kind of wrapper script?

Comment: I ran this  /home/sgadamse/history_checker/code/a.py command manually and it worked. Yes its just a rg binary that i downloaded from their website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's `man rg`:

> ripgrep will automatically detect if stdin exists and search stdin for a regex pattern, e.g. `ls | rg foo`. In some environments, stdin may exist when it shouldn’t. To turn off stdin detection explicitly specify the directory to search, e.g. `rg foo ./`.

Vixie Cron is one such environment, because for whichever reason [it sets stdin to a closed pipe](https://github.com/vixie/cron/blob/690fc534c7316e2cf6ff16b8e83ba7734b5186d2/do_command.c#L92) instead of a more typical redirection from `/dev/null`:

```
        /* create some pipes to talk to our future child
         */  
        pipe(stdin_pipe);       /* child's stdin */
```

So you should be able to reproduce it in your shell with `true | python .../a.py`, and fix it by adding a path as suggested in the manual (`rg "hello" ./`)